# This is how right I am, but what am I?

Tags: riddle

> If I take it steady, I am only right once,
>
> but if I'm wrong, I stay wrong.
>
> If I stand still, I am right twice.
>
> but if I go backwards, I am right four times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you :

> A clock?

If I'm steady, I am only right once

> If you stay on the right time, you're always right

but if I'm wrong, I stay wrong.

> If you're off, but working, you'll never have the right time

If I stand still, I am right twice.

> A broken clock is right twice a day

but if I go backwards, I am right four times.

> A clock running backwards is right four times a day

Comment: why is right once and always right the same?

Comment: Because, @Andrey , that once is the present moment, and if the clock is right, it will ALWAYS be the present moment. Hence the clock will always be right once. Hope this helped.  :)